# Explaining Van der Waals interaction through zero point energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, dipole

When talking about Van der Waals interaction between instantaneous/induced dipoles, the well known textbook *Introduction to Solid State Physics* by Charles Kittel chooses to illustrate the concept by considering the two dipoles as two identical linear oscillators with opposite charges at their extremities (for some reason, StackExchange add picture is not working, so I cannot add an image of the system; anyway, the modeled system looks as follows: each oscillator is a spring connecting a positive charge (on the left) with a negative one (on the right). The distance between the charges in the oscillators are $x_1$ and $x_2$, and the separation between the positive charge of the first oscillator and the negative charge of the second is $R$).

The hamiltonian of the **uncoupled** system is hence

$H_0 = \dfrac{p^2_1}{2m} + \dfrac{p^2_2}{2m} + \dfrac{1}{2}m\omega_0^2x_1^2 + \dfrac{1}{2}m\omega_0^2x_2^2$

where $\omega_0$ is the angular frequency of the strongest optical absorption line of the atom. I have some doubts already: why choose exactly the frequency of the strongest absorption line of the atom? And what is the mass $m$ in the Hamiltonian? Is it understood to be the sum of the masses of the two charges in each oscillator?

The coupling term in the hamiltonian is electrostatic and can be approximated as

$H_1 = \dfrac{-e^2x_1x_2}{R^2} \qquad \text{(CGS system)}$

By exploiting the change of variables

$x_s = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x_1 + x_2) \qquad \qquad x_a = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x_1 - x_2)$

which implies

$x_1 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x_s + x_a) \qquad \qquad x_2 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x_s - x_a)$

and the associated momenta

$p_1 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(p_s + p_a) \qquad \qquad p_2 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(p_s - p_a)$

one can finally rewrite the total Hamiltonian as

$H = \left[ \dfrac{p_s^2}{2m} + \dfrac{1}{2}\left(m\omega_0^2 - \dfrac{2e^2}{R^3}\right)x_s^2 \right] + \left[ \dfrac{p_a^2}{2m} + \dfrac{1}{2}\left(m\omega_0^2 + \dfrac{2e^2}{R^3}\right)x_a^2 \right]$

which reveals that the angular frequencies of the coupled oscillators are

$\omega = \left[ \left( m\omega_0^2 \pm \dfrac{2e^2}{R^3}  \right) /m \right]^{1/2} = \omega_0 \left[ 1 \pm \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{2e^2}{m\omega_0^2R^3} - \dfrac{1}{8} \left( \dfrac{2e^2}{m\omega_0^2R^3} \right)^2 + \dots \right] $

The textbook goes then on to conclude that the zero point energy of the system is $ \dfrac{1}{2}\hbar \left(\omega_s + \omega_a \right) $ and that this means that the zero point energy of the system has decreased, due to the interaction, from $ 2 \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} \hbar \omega_0 $ by

$ \Delta U = -\hbar \omega_0 \dfrac{1}{8} \left(\dfrac{2e^2}{m\omega_0^2R^3}\right)^2 = -\dfrac{A}{R^6}$

The textbook then says the van der Waals attraction must grow like $R^{-6}$.

I have some questions, both on the concept of zero point energy and on this final conclusion. Why is the zero-point energy of an oscillator $\dfrac{1}{2} \hbar \omega_0$? Also, I noticed the expression of the zero-point energy has the same form of the quantum vibrational energy. Is it vibrational energy? And if it is, why are we not assuming, for instance, a "zero-point rotational energy"? The system can clearly also rotate. How can we conclude that all of the energy that is not anymore in the zero point contribution is now "stored" in the attraction between dipoles?